# ¿Como puedo quitar algunas columnas de una tabla en c# que traigo desde Mysql?

Tags: c#

Quiero mostrar solo algunos de los campos que traigo desde mi consulta, pero a la hora de visualizarlos me aparecen todos en el grid

```
List<Pojos.agregarProducto> lstProd = new List<Pojos.agregarProducto>();
        MySqlDataReader dr;

        MySqlCommand cm = new MySqlCommand("select nombres,cantidad,precio,total" +
            " from venta_Producto where idVenta =" + id, cn.Conectar());
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            Pojos.agregarProducto objAp = new Pojos.agregarProducto();
            objAp.Nombres = dr.GetString("nombres");
            objAp.Cantidad = dr.GetDouble("cantidad");
            objAp.Precio = dr.GetDouble("precio");
            objAp.Total = dr.GetDouble("total");

            lstProd.Add(objAp);
        }
        cn.Cerrar();
        return lstProd;
    }
```

Comment: Si la grilla esta tiene autogenerate columns en true, sacalo y defini a mano las columnas. Pero en realidad, la mejor solucion, es no traigas las columnas que no queres. es un sinsentido ya que no las necesitas y solo haces mas pesado el pasaje de datos (y lentificas la consulta en algunos casos)

Comment: Aquí: `select nombres,cantidad,precio,total" ...` pon solamente las columnas que necesitas, no pongas columnas de más, no es bueno desde el punto de vista de la optimización/rendimiento.

Comment: es que esas son las los campos que necesito, de hecho la tabla tiene mas campos. Pero ya pude solucionarlo, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrias hacer es lo siguiente:

```
 return lstProd.Select(model => new { model.nombres,
                                      model.cantidad,
                                      model.precio,
                                      model.total
                                    });
```